# Laravel how to get similar/most count records in a row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, database

I have a table like this

```
id     worktime_l        
1         120                 
1         120                 
1         150                 
1         210                 
1         120
```

I want to get the majority or have the most count of the records. Since there are 3 120's in the table. Query must return `120`. Also, if the values are independent. I should get the lowest one. Is that possible in Laravel or in MySQL? . Thanks in advance.

Comment: GROUP BY, COUNT(), ORDER BY LIMIT 1

Comment: can you share your query sir?

Comment: `SELECT worktime_l FROM tablename GROUP BY worktime_l ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, worktime_l ASC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Do you need the original records or just the work time value?

Comment: just worktime value sir @TimBiegeleisen. most count of similar record

Comment: ok will try this one @Akina

Comment: @Akina. but how can i also get the lowest value when the records have different values each? can both written in one query?

Comment: Do you want both most often and the least `worktime_l` values to be combined in one returned row as 2 separate  columns? if so then use above query as subquery and another subquery which gets the least value, and CROSS JOIN them.

Comment: i think the query you give is the answer. i tried putting different values and it returns the lowest one. however, is it possible in querybuilder in laravel? @Akina

Comment: I don't use laravel and hence don't know how to use subqueries in it.

Comment: @Patas yes that's possible in Laravel

Comment: `DB::table('tablename')
->select('worktime_l')
->groupBy('worktime_l')
->orderByRaw('COUNT(*) DESC, worktime_l ASC LIMIT 1')`

Try this

Comment: thanks bro @groovy_guy. you can write your answer so i can give u credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::table('tablename')
->select('worktime_l')
->groupBy('worktime_l')
->orderByRaw('COUNT(*) DESC, worktime_l ASC LIMIT 1')
```

Here it is,